# Why does FlaUI fail to find elements at times?

Tags: c#, testing, automation, flaui

my code is below

```
IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(null, "dingding");
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out dingID);
var myapp = FlaUI.Core.Application.Attach(dingID);
var myautomation = new UIA3Automation());
var searchTextBox = dingdingWindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf => cf.ByName("search"))?.AsTextBox();
```

most time  it  works well but sometimes when it goes to  "var serchTextBox........", the result is null and the hwnd is ok  and  dingID is ok and searchTextBox is spotted with inspect.exe. I have to relaunch my app, then everything goes fine.

I am just curious about that? Can somebody tell me why and how to modify the code?

Comment: It might be a timing issue. The control you are looking for might not be initialized yet, even though its parent window already exists. I usually implement a retry loop to try to find the control periodically, with a short delay after each unsuccessful try. If after a given amount of time the control still can't be found, I throw a timeout exception.

Comment: i've try a lot to find out  which part is null ,   dingdingwindows  or elements .  the conclusion is  dingdingwindow is ok  when i use" if dingdingwindows is null  throw SystemException" . but  when i  use "var allObj = dingdingWindow.FindAllChildren();"   ,  the result is null .  strange!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your application and the complexity of its initialization, the control might not be there the moment the statement is executed, but milliseconds later (when you look at it with FlaUInspect) it is.

When looking for controls, especially right after start or after invoking some menu item that calls up a dialog etc., give the UI a bit of time to catch up. `Retry.WhileNull()` allows this very conveniently.

```
var searchTextBox = Retry.WhileNull(
    () => dingdingWindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf => cf.ByName("search"),
    timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
    throwOnTimeout: true,
    timeoutMessage: "Could not find Search control")
    .Result;
```